# Ground/outlet tester shows bad ground for entire house after switching single outlet

Tags: receptacle, grounding

I just changed out a receptacle.  Prior to changing I tested the original receptacle with a ground & outlet tester.  It showed everything to be wired correctly (green light).  After installing the new receptacle every single outlet in the house shows bad ground.  I removed the outlet, checked the grounding-wires pigtail; everything looked good.

I checked voltages as well: neutral-to-hot showed 110 for both outlets, ground-to-hot showed 110 for both outlets, neutral-to-ground showed 0V.

My guess is the tester is bad; does that make sense or am I missing something else?  Is there anything else to check at this point?

Comment: Sounds like a rubbish tester.  The "best" testers have 3 lights: red yellow yellow, basically 3 neon-light testers connected neutral-ground, hot-neutral, and hot-ground. There is then a legend that gives a hilariously wrong interpretation of the lights.  Lately, we've seen testers with a green light.  Those insert a computer in between you and the lights; the computer interprets the lights *for you*, so it gives you the hilariously wrong conclusion directly.  These are worse than useless, because at least the first one is 3 neon testers in one package.

Comment: Good to know.  I'll have to get a new one.  I got over to my neighbor's today and tested my tester there: same result.  I then borrowed his tester (a red, yellow, yellow type) and it showed everything is fine.  Thanks for the tip on a "good" tester.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/158766/what-does-a-receptacle-tester-reading-of-correct-really-mean/158773#158773

Comment: Come on Harper you forgot to call them magic 8 ball testers I have been using that term since I first saw you post it because those testers are correct about as often as a magic 8 ball.

Comment: @EdBeal thank you :) Oh, I wanted to, but I was out of space!